# Access-Control-Allow-Origin error when using Owin

Tags: asp.net, .net, owin, aurelia

I'm have a aurelia client and a webserver. When i use localhost and i'm running on the same machine it works fine.

But when i want to access the server from another machine the page loads but the api calls give the following error:
No `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header is present on the requested resource.

I'm using owin and to my undestanding i need to enable CORS for owin.

I did the follwing in my startup class:-

UPDATE
I have updated my class with input from Nenad but is still get the same error.
Below i have added the call from the client.

```
 public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {

            this.container = new Container();
            // Create the container as usual.
            container.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle = new AsyncScopedLifestyle();

            // Register your types, for instance using the scoped lifestyle:
            container.Register<IWebDeps, WebDeps>(Lifestyle.Singleton);

            // This is an extension method from the integration package.
            container.RegisterWebApiControllers(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration, Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

            container.Verify();

            app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);

            // Configure Web API for self-host. 
            var config = new HttpConfiguration()
            {
                DependencyResolver =
                new SimpleInjectorWebApiDependencyResolver(container)
            };

            var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");
            config.EnableCors(cors);

            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
            //// Custom Middleare
            app.Use(typeof(CustomMiddleware));
            app.UseWebApi(config);

            //New code:
            app.Run(context =>
            {
                context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
                return context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello, world.");
            });
        }
```

My main program is calling the startUp class:-

```
  using (Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.WebApp.Start<Startup>("http://localhost:8080"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Press [enter] to quit...");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
```

Client code, 192.168.178.23 is the ip from the server.

```
let baseUrl2 = "http://192.168.178.23:8080/api/status/getStatus";
    getStatus() {
        return this.client.get(baseUrl2)
            .then(response => {
                return this.parseJSONToObject(response.content);
        });
    }
```

The error in Chrome:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://192.168.178.23:8080/api/status/getStatus. No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:9000' is therefore not allowed
>   access. The response had HTTP status code 400.

Cors should be enabled now right? But i still get the error when doing a api call. Am i missing any steps? Our is this approah wrong?

Any suggestions are welcome!

Comment: I would try to add the line `app.UseWebApi(config);`, maybe this is needed to associate `app` that has the CORS setup with the routes in `config`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that when starting OWIN the adres should be http://*:8080. Instead of local host.

Answer (score 2):

You have to configure WebAPI to work with CORS.

1. Install Nuget package:

   ```
   Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors
   ```
2. Enable CORS on `HttpConfiguration` object:

   ```
   config.EnableCors();
   ```
3. Add `[EnableCors]` attribute on your controller:

   ```
   using System.Net.Http;
   using System.Web.Http;
   using System.Web.Http.Cors;

   namespace WebService.Controllers
   {
       [EnableCors(origins: "www.example.com", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
       public class TestController : ApiController
       {
       // Controller methods not shown...
       }
   }
   ```

   or register it globally via `HttpConfig`:

   ```
   var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("www.example.com", "*", "*");
   config.EnableCors(cors);
   ```

More details at: [Enabling Cross-Origin Requests in ASP.NET Web API 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api)

Comment: Thank you for you're answer,. I will try this now. Does this work when you use OWIN?

Comment: Hi Nenad, i have tried you're solution but i'm getting the same error. I have added the client code of the api call for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line and check,

```
 app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);
```

and remove,

```
var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");
        config.EnableCors(cors);
```

this worked for me.

Comment: Hi thanks for you're comment. I tried that one but still no result